# How to replace substring in a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, replace

I have a string (i.e `If you ask the makers of paper products, they will tell you that to be Agile you need to write ...`) and the search terms (i.e `['makers', 'to be Agile']`).

I expect this result `If you ask the <strong>makers</strong> of paper products, they will tell you that <strong>to</strong> <strong>be</strong> <strong>Agile</strong> you need to write ...`

I implement that with this method but sometimes doesn't work correctly.

```
private emphasize(text: string, highlights: string[]) {
    return highlights
      .filter(highlight => text.includes(highlight))
      .map(highlight => highlight.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))
      .reduce((txt, highlight) => {
        return txt.replace(new RegExp(highlight, 'gi'), '<strong>$&</strong>');
      }, text);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a RegExp by joining the `highlights` with the pipe `|` symbol, and wrapping with word boundaries (`\b`). Now use `String.replace()` to wrap found strings with `<strong>`. This will wrap entire expressions (to be Agile) with `<strong>`.

```js
function emphasize(text, highlights) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`\\b${highlights.join('|')}\\b`, 'gi');

  return text.replace(pattern, '<strong>$&</strong>');
}

const text = 'If you ask the makers of paper products, they will tell you that to be Agile you need to write';
const highlights = ['makers', 'to be Agile'];

const result = emphasize(text, highlights);

console.log(result);
```

If you really want single words, join the highlights with spaces, then split by spaces and join again with the pipe symbol:

```js
function emphasize(text, highlights) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`\\b${highlights.join(' ').split(' ').join('|')}\\b`, 'gi');

  return text.replace(pattern, '<strong>$&</strong>');
}

const text = 'If you ask the makers of paper products, they will tell you that to be Agile you need to write';
const highlights = ['makers', 'to be Agile'];

const result = emphasize(text, highlights);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should warn OP of the caveats related to word boundary usage. It won't work if the keywords start/end with special chars, like `['C++', '.NET code']`